# PHP como controlo la pagina perfil para quienes intentan acceder sin estar conectados?

Tags: php, php7, session, sesiones

tengo mi `inicio.php` , el cual **solo deberia entrar quien ha iniciado sesion** y si no que se muestre por ejemplo un `<h1>Debes iniciar sesion</h1>`.

Se me ocurrio esto:

```
<?php 
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {


 ?>

 <!DOCTYPE html>
 <html lang="en">
 <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio</title>
 </head>
 <body>

    <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'] ?></h1>
    <a href="procesos/logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>

 </body>
 </html>

 <?php 


    }


    else{
        echo "<h1>Debes iniciar sesion antes de acceder a esta pagina</h1>";
    }

  ?>
```

Pero me parece muy burda, **existe una forma mas formal de hacerlo** y **¿se suele usar esta forma que hice yo?**

Comment: No veo una duda concreta de código, es decir esto funciona o no? por que si esperas opiniones eso será motivo de cierre

Comment: Mas que una opinion hablaba de alternativa.

Comment: sigue siendo búsqueda de opiniones con base en la experiencia de otros usuarios, lo cual genera no una sino múltiples respuestas

Comment: te recomiendo que el if de validación este completo en la parte de arriba si esta loggeado no pasara nada pero en caso contrario entrara en el else, sin necesidad de ponerlo en la parte de abajo

Comment: Que dices que meta todo el html dentro de la etiqueta `php` ?

Comment: @josanangel <?php 
    session_start();

    if (isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {

    }
    else{
        echo "<h1>Debes iniciar sesion antes de acceder a esta pagina</h1>";
    }

 ?>

Comment: abajo de tu if pon tu html, esto ayuda a que si no esta loggeado no tenga que pasar por todo antes y directamente ya saque el mensaje

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo que puedes hacer es que antes de que la página cargue por completo, tu evaluas si el usuario está registrado o no mediante la variable de sesión. Si esto no es así (el usuario no está registrado) lo rediriges a la página de login. El código quedaría algo así:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    header("Location:login.php"); //Se redireccionará al usuario en caso de que la variable de sesión "Usiario" no exista, o lo que es lo mismo a que el usuario no esté registrado.
    exit();
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'] ?></h1>
    <a href="procesos/logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>

</body>
</html>
```

En algún dado caso solo quieres imprimir un texto (ya sea por motivos de aprendizaje o por lo que sea) puedes usar este código:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['usuario'])) {
    echo "<h1>Debes iniciar sesion antes de acceder a esta pagina</h1>";
    exit();
}
 ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Inicio</title>
</head>

<body>

    <h1>Bienvenido <?php echo $_SESSION['usuario'] ?></h1>
    <a href="procesos/logout.php">Cerrar Sesion</a>

</body>
</html>
```

La encargada de permitir que la página no termine de cargar es la función `exit();`, la cual nos permite detener el flujo de cargado de la página.

Espero te sirva.

Comment: Para que sirve el `exit();` exactamente  ? para que **no siga cargando lo que hay despues ?** como una especie de `break` ?

Comment: Exactamente. exi(); te permite cortar el flujo de cargado de la página. Es cómo un break pero de toda la página.

Answer (score 1):

En mi caso particular uso una estructura como la siguiente, quizás te puede servir de orientación.

```
<?php
session_start();

require_once '../common/classes.php'; 
# classes.php contiene los metodos comunes: conexion a DB, querys, formato de fecha, etc.

class MiClase extends Common_Class {
    function __construct() {
        // Metodo inicial
    }

    public function display_body() {
        // Rutina 1
    }

    public function metodo_2() {
        // Rutina 2
    }

    public function metodo_N() {
        // Rutina N
    }
}

// ###### INICIA AQUI #######
if(isset($_SESSION['usr_id'])) {
    $interface = new MiClase();
    require_once 'header.php'; // Archivo que contiene el HTML superior de la pagina y los menus
    if($_SESSION['usr_privilege'] > 0) { 
        // Esta pagina requiere privilegios aunque este logueado correctamente (por ej, settings.php)
        // Si es una pagina común, entonces quita este if - else.
        $interface->display_body();
    } else {
        echo '<p>[!] No tienes autorizaci&oacute;n para ver esta p&aacute;gina.<p>';
    }
    require_once 'footer.php'; // Footer y cierre HTML
} else {
    // Si no esta logueado
    header("location:login.php");
}
```

Ahora bien, si quieres mostrar el mensaje de "Debes iniciar sesión" hay que reemplazar el `header` del último `else` por ese mensaje. Pero adicional habría que subir el `require_once 'header.php';` antes del primer `if`, y el `footer.php` después del cierre del ultimo `else`, para que el mensaje quede impreso en pantalla con todos los formatos correctos.